# Is it okay to ignore basis in matrix computations despite different geometrical results?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

I'm reading linear algebra done right by Axler and I've been confused with the basis. For instance,

Let's say $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ where $V$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$, $v_1 = (4,2), v_2=(5,3)$, and let 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{cc}
   &  \begin{array}{ccc}  &  v_1 & v_2   \end{array}\\
\mathcal{M}(T, (v_1, v_2)) = & \begin{array}{c} v_1\\ v_2\end{array} 
  \left(\begin{array}{cc}
    4 & 5\\
    2 & 3\\
  \end{array}\right)
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
This implies that $Tv_1 = 4v_1 + 2v_2$ since
$$   \begin{array}{cc}
   &  \begin{array}{ccc}   \end{array}\\
\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 5 \\ 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}= & \begin{array}{c} v_1\\ v_2\end{array} 
  \left(\begin{array}{cc}
    4\\
    2 \\
  \end{array}\right)
\end{array}$$

However, if $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$, $v_1 = (4,2), v_2=(5,3), w_1=(1,0), w_2=(0,1)$, and let 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{cc}
   &  \begin{array}{ccc}  &  v_1 & v_2   \end{array}\\
\mathcal{M}(T, (v_1, v_2), (w_1, w_2)) = & \begin{array}{c} w_1\\ w_2\end{array} 
  \left(\begin{array}{cc}
    4 & 5\\
    2 & 3\\
  \end{array}\right)
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
This implies that $Tv_1 = 4w_1 + 2w_2$ since
$$   \begin{array}{cc}
   &  \begin{array}{ccc}   \end{array}\\
\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 5 \\ 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}= & \begin{array}{c} w_1\\ w_2\end{array} 
  \left(\begin{array}{cc}
    4\\
    2 \\
  \end{array}\right)
\end{array}$$

The two results are completely different geometrically, but if we omit the bases, the numerical results are the same. Often in statistics or in other matrix computations, bases are not given. My quetions are:

1. In most matrix computations that we see in our other math textbooks, how are the bases defined (especially when the matrix is not a square matrix)? For instance, in statistics, we often have the data matrix $X$ and its size is $N \times d$ where $N$ is the number of samples and $d$ is the feature size. What can we say about the bases?
2. Is it okay to ignore the bases despite different geometrical interpretations?

Comment: What is $\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: @PPR $\mathcal{M}$ is the matrix. So $\mathcal{M}(T)$ means the matrix of a linear mapping $T$. It's the notation used by Axler in his book.

Comment: So in this notation you specify both the operator and the basis for that matrix, ok. What is $W$?

Comment: @PPR $W$ and $V$ are vector spaces

Comment: As to your questions: usually the *standard* basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is assumed implicitly, especially if there is no other specification. You can never ignore the base, but you can make its choice implicit and forget about it. Whether it is OK to do so or not depends on the application in mind, e.g., in physics, most things one cares about are basis independent, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @PPR how do you implicitly choose the bases when the matrix isn't a square matrix?

Comment: You use the standard basis. I don't see why it matters if the matrix is square or not?

Comment: The linear operator $T$ is defined without any basis. When we take a basis $v_i$, then the basis determines a matrix as $Tv_i = \sum T_i^j v_j$. If you take a distinct base $w_i$ for the target space, then the pair of bases ( $\{v_i\} \{w_i\}$ ) determine a different matrix by $Tv_i = \sum \tilde{T}_i^jw_j$.

Comment: it's not a different matrix.  It's the same matrix, the same rectangular array of numbers.  (You wrote as much in your question.)  What is different is the linear map.  The linear map turns abstract vectors into abstract vectors.  Once you choose a basis, the numbers in the matrix of your rectangular array are specified.  So are the numbers in the lists of components of the vectors.  Changing the basis changes the numbers in the matrices and the numbers in the vectors in such a way that the same abstract vector is sent to the same abstract vector.